# SQL Cursor value in single group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I am using a SQL cursor. I want to select the values

```
While(@@fetchstatus ==0)
BEGIN
  if(cond)
    SELECT rownumber, rowname FROM TABLE
END
```

During the first round of execution of While loop I am getting the value.

1,"Firstrow"(From Row select)

Next

2,"SecondRow"

All these values are displayed in my output as separate rows. Is it possible to combine and display as two outputs like this

> 1, "FirstRow"
>
> 2,"SecondRow"

Comment: I'd like to help, but I find this difficult to read & understand what you are trying to communicate.

Comment: @Ponies I have edited do you need more

Comment: Why wouldn't a SELECT work - placing the Cond in the "Where" clause? I might be wrong, but this sounds like a classic case of someone reaching for a cursor because they are more familiar with procedural programming than the set-based development characteristic of SQL.  So...can you provide any more detail?  Is it just that you want to print the results?  Well, you *still* don't need a cursor - at least if you are working in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you realy need the loop over the cursor, this might be helpful:

```
-- create temptable
select top 0 rownumber, rowname 
into #temp
from table

-- loop through your cursor
While(@@fetchstatus ==0)
BEGIN
  if(cond)
  begin
    insert into #temp
    SELECT rownumber, rowname FROM TABLE
  end
END

select rownumber, rowname from #temp

drop #temp
```